# How to reset a Completion Handler in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a function. It runs great but when I want to call it again it knows that that function has already been completed before so if I try to call it again it will automatically pass to completed. How do I reset the completion handler?

Code:

```
func Test(completionHandler: @escaping (_ finished: String?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
        completionHandler("finished") // tell the caller that this has completed
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
self.Test(completionHandler: { finished in
     print("We have completed function)")
})
```

If I were to call it again after about a minute. Instead of it waiting 10 seconds like its supposed. It will automatically printed line.

```
print("We have completed function)")
```

**Things to know:**

The code above is a test example me real code is this.

```
   func GoToPage(completionHandler: @escaping (_ finished: String?) -> Void) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('results').getElementsByClassName('page')[0].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
        } else {
        print(value)
        completionHandler("finished")
        }
        }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
     self.GoToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
     print("We have completed function)")
     })
```

Then I wait one 1-2 minutes and call it again like this the same way.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 130.0) {
     self.GoToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
     print("We have completed function")
     })
    }
```

An it prints me the line We have completed function right off the bat when called.

**EXAMPLE:**

This puts it all together

```
     self.GoToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
     print("We have completed function)")
     NextStep()
     })


     func NextStep(){
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 130.0) {
     self.GoToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
     print("We have completed function")
     })
     }
     }


     func GoToPage(completionHandler: @escaping (_ finished: String?) -> Void) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('results').getElementsByClassName('page')[0].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText"){ (value, error) in
        if error != nil {
        } else {
        print(value)
        completionHandler("finished")
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: This is a very confusing question. What do you mean by *"it knows that that function has already been completed before"*? Show an example demonstrating your issue.

Comment: I updated Question

Comment: How are you waiting a minute and then calling `Test` again?

Comment: I update my Answer

Comment: But how are you waiting? What actual action triggers the 2nd call? Are you tapping a button and the button action calls `GoToPage`? Are you using `sleep`? What exactly?

Comment: Ok, I've tried *twice to edit you poorly indented code in hopes to understand the issue, but your edits get in the way. Could you please do one last edit? Use correct `if...then` indentation on your code? Thanks.

Comment: Haha wow Im really sorry. Im done editing now you can make your changes .

Comment: @Hunter: How are you calling self.GoToPage? If I check your code in playground, it works as expected. Let me edit my answer. Also, please use camel case for function names.

Comment: The self.GoToPage(completionHandler: etc. Is the call to the func GoToPage(completionHandler

Comment: @Hunter: No i mean, how are you calling this function? It can't me hanging around is it? I guess its a view controller where you have written this code. Are you calling self.GoToPage on viewDidLoad or at some button press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as it is supposed to work.
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is an async function, i.e. when you are calling the `self.test`, the function returns after asking main thread to asynchronously wait for 10 seconds, and then immediately you ask the function to do the same for second time. 
If you want the function to wait for the first execution, one way to do this is to call the function for second time in its completion handler:

```
self.Test(completionHandler: { finished in
    print("We have completed function)")
    self.Test(completionHandler: { finished in
        print("We have completed function)")
    })
})
```

**EDIT:** code in playground. Prints second function after about 10 seconds.

```
class TestAsyncAfter {

    func nextStep(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
            self.goToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
                print("We have completed function")
            })
        }
    }

    func goToPage(completionHandler: @escaping (_ finished: String?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler("finished")
    }
}

let test = TestAsyncAfter()
test.goToPage(completionHandler: { finished in
    print("We have completed function")
    test.nextStep()
})

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: ok I'm a little confused. I call the function 1 time at the start then I wait about 2 minutes and call it again and it automatically prints me the line.

Comment: @Hunter: Show the code where you are waiting for 2 minutes.

Comment: Hmmm ok maybe its something else wrong with some other part of my code then well ill mark as answer then. Since this seem to be correct